# GLFW doesn't recognize Xbox Controller

Tags: java, controller, lwjgl, glfw

LWJGL version: *3.1.4 build 8*
GLFW version: *3.3.0 Win32 WGL EGL VisualC DLL*

The controller shows up in the device manager as *Xbox Controller* under *Xbox Peripherals* and seems to be working fine in games.

However, trying *glfwJoystickPresent()* only returns false:

```
for (int joy = GLFW_JOYSTICK_1; joy<=GLFW_JOYSTICK_LAST;joy++) {    
    System.out.println(joy+": "+glfwJoystickPresent(joy))
}
```

Is the Xbox One controller not supported? Is there faulty hardware at play? Is there anything else I'm missing?

Edit: This is my complete code:

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;

public class FuckingControllerInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(Version.getVersion());
        System.out.println(glfwGetVersionString());
        for (int joy = GLFW_JOYSTICK_1; joy<=GLFW_JOYSTICK_LAST;joy++) {
            System.out.println(joy+": "+glfwJoystickPresent(joy));
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XBox controllers should be supported, there were some conversations here talking about it

http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/glfw-controller-database/37754/view.html

With out you posting any other code or providing more details of your controller it is hard to tell what is wrong. Try the controller test program in the link to see if you get recognition of your controller. Other people definitely have had luck with xbox controllers.

Comment: Thank you. The controller works in the test program, but not in mine. The for loop I posted is pretty much my only code (except for imports).

Comment: Have you initialised GLFW? (edit : looks like you haven't, try adding GLFW.glfwInit())

Comment: Geez, that solved it, thanks. I should have read the intro guide before jumping straight into the input guide. Thank you!